# @ContributesAndroidInjector's module alternative in Hilt

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2, dagger-hilt

With Dagger2 we can add a module to `@ContributesAndroidInjector` so that the associated `Activity` or `Fragment` becomes available in the generated subcomponent. The official documentation is here: https://dagger.dev/dev-guide/android

This feature is particularly useful for extracting e.g. the arguments passed to the `Activity` (or `Fragment`) and passing their content directly to the `ViewModel`.

For example:

`myApp/featurex/src/main/kotlin/com/example/featurex/FeatureXFragment.kt`

```kotlin
class FeatureXFragment : Fragment() {

    // ... everything else here ...

    @Module
    interface InjectorModule {
        @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = [ArgsModule::class])
        fun contributesFeatureXFragment(): FeatureXFragment
    }

    // This module is installed **only** in the subcomponent generated by @ContributesAndroidInjector
    // which makes FeatureXFragment accessible to the provider.
    @Module
    class ArgsModule {
        @Provides
        fun providesEntityId(featureXFragment: FeatureXFragment): String {
            return featureXFragment.requireArguments().getString(ENTITY_ID_EXTRA)!!
        }
    }

    companion object {
        const val ENTITY_ID_EXTRA = "ENTITY_ID_EXTRA"
    }
}
```

`myApp/featurex/src/main/kotlin/com/example/featurex/FeatureXFragmentViewModel.kt`

```kotlin
class FeatureXFragmentViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val entityId: String,
) : ViewModel() {
    // ...
}
```

The `ArgsModule` is installed **only** in the subcomponent generated for `FeatureXFragment` by `@ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = [ArgsModule::class])` annotation. This allows the `ArgsModule` to access `FeatureXFragment` in the `@Provides`-annotated method in a type-safe manner, i.e. the `ArgsModule` won't be used for any other `Fragment` in the app, therefore e.g. casting such as `fragment as FeatureXFragment` is not necessary.

If I remember correctly (sorry, it's been a long time since I used it this way), if we have multiple `Fragment`s in the codebase and all of their corresponding `ArgsModule`s provide the same type e.g. a `String`, they won't collide with each other even though we don't use any qualifiers for them (like `@Named`).

I have an impression there is no alternative in Hilt for the behavior described above, i.e. we can't install a `@Module` in a subcomponent of a **specific** `Fragment`.

Do you know if something like this can be done in Hilt too?

Answer (score 2):

In Hilt, there is no easy way to inject an argument directly into a `ViewModel`. Does this mean we are unable to pass arguments to the `ViewModel` in `Hilt`? Fortunately, there is a way. We can use `SavedStateHandle`, which allows storing and retrieving a Fragment's state, hence also accessing the Fragment's arguments.

Here's an example of how to do it:

```
@HiltViewModel
class FeatureXFragmentViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle
) : ViewModel() {
    val entityId: String = savedStateHandle.get<String>("ENTITY_ID_EXTRA")!!
    // ...
}
```

In this case, `SavedStateHandle` is injected into the `ViewModel`. It provides access to the Fragment's arguments, allowing us to retrieve the value of `ENTITY_ID_EXTRA`.

This is not an ideal solution to the problem as it does not provide us with such granular control as `Dagger2`, but it is a way to achieve similar functionality in `Hilt`.

Comment: Thanks. I know I can do that but passing arguments to the ViewModel was only a specific example of the possibilities provided by a module installed in a Fragment's subcomponent. `SavedStateHandle` is a good alternative in that particular scenario but it's not the same as having a dedicated module where I can provide anything I want (not necessarily related to the Fragment or the arguments).